# WFR Not running

Tags: community, workflowoutboundmessage, workflowrule

so I have a WFR that's triggered by a check Box being set to true, this check box is on Account, WFR is supposed to RUN when: created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria
But for some reason, it's not firing the outbound.

Does anyone know what are the requirements for a WFR to fire when it's set to meet (created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria)?
I feel like it's not firing maybe because there is another field that's being updated at the same time that's why it's thinking it's just another edit on the record, not the specific field update?

Please let me know if you have any clues!

....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WFRs evaluate all the criteria first, then execute their actions. Therefore, if it was a Field Update that checked the box, the WFR that performs the Field Update must also specify "reevaluate workflow rules" in order for a second pass on the WFR evaluations so the Outbound Message (or any other actions) would be executed. Otherwise, using "created, or subsequently edited to meet the criteria" will never fire in the Field Update scenario, unless a user manually checks the box.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox thanks for your reply, so it's a Quick action button that updates the field checkbox to TRUE it there where I could have to set reevaluate workflow rules?